# Step height unusual

Tags: wood

How would you deal with a 10 1/2 inch step. We raised the bathroom floor in basement 10 1/2 inches but now have to make a step. Would you make two equal steps 5 1/4 inches or do a 7 inch step followed by a  3 1/2 inch step?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. The end of your question is confusing; could you clarify what you mean by "7 inch step with 3 1"?

Comment: What I meat to say was have 2 equal steps or make the first step 7 inches high with the remaining 3 1/2 inches as the finial step to the bathroom. Or vice a versa but ....now I think two equal steps are best though....

Comment: I moved your comment info into the question.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's not a stair there's not really any governing law. But, common practice is to not have any step. However, to be considerate of the human body's **need** for symmetry or regularity (the good kind), 2 equal steps would be best (calculate bath flooring into step height).

Though, if the bathroom's just getting started consider re-doing the floor after the plumbing to raise it more (if possible & to match the rest of the place's steps) or of course to lower it for a single 7" or 8" step. Or, will the basement floor be re-finished? As in, insulated & thereby raised inches.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. No plans now to add flooring on basement. The 1/2 bath is linoleum so little additional floor height there.  Not enough head room in the bathroom to  raise the floor another 4 or so inches. Husband wouldn't  be happy with lowering floor and changing all that. Don't know what is under there as to why height is what it is.....bathroom been this height since we moved in. Used a moveable platform before that was 4 and 1/2 inches high. This has been an awkward step for years.

Comment: I figured you might be stuck, but I had to throw out some things. Definitely, add the one step for a nice even 5-1/4" climb into the bathroom. You're actually lucky you can do a step, so you'll be just fine.